# Displaying a cell array of strings in a convenient, elegant and robust way

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Often, my functions contain a string argument that has a small number of valid options. For example, it might represent a mode similar to the last argument of `interp1`. When the user passes an incorrect value, I like to give a list of valid options in the error message.

Currently, I solve it like this:

```
function out = my_func(mode)
valid_modes = {'rectangular', 'gaussian'};
switch mode
    case 'rectangular'
        % do something
    case 'gaussian'
        % do something else
    otherwise
        error(['atmlab:' mfilename ':invalid'], 'Invalid mode: %s. Valid modes: %s', mode, sprintf('%s ', valid_modes))
end
```

The trick I'm exploiting is that `sprintf` can take a cell array, and then outputs a concatenation of multiple strings. However, this behaviour appears to be undocumented, and as of Matlab 2012b, Matlabs Code Analyzer has started to warn against this usage of `sprintf`. It still works, but it might not be a supported way and I don't know if it will remain working in the future, so I'm reluctant to simply ignore or suppress the warning.

Another solution would be to use `evalc('disp(valid_modes)')`, but that solution makes me puke.

How do I conveniently and elegantly display the value of a cell array of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since recent versions of Matlab (I think since 2013b), there is a new function [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html), that joins strings in a cell array.  For example:

```
C = {'Newton','Gauss','Euclid','Lagrange'};  
str = strjoin(C,', ')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sprintf` this way, using [lists](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)

```
sprintf('%s ', valid_modes{:})
```

That works. I am actually surprised that you can write it the way you did. I get an error.

Going now the more complicated route :) You can always do this

```
str = [valid_modes{:}]; % that is a string
```

You just need to include spaces inside the mode names, which you probably don't want to do. But you can declare them to include spaces in the second row:

```
valid_modes = {'rectangular'    'gaussian'
               ' '              ' '} 
str = [valid_modes{:}]
ans =

 rectangular gaussian
```

Comment: Hm, apropos the error, I must have gotten confused with something else. I'm not sure anymore what I did in the past...

Answer (score 3):

This is a one-liner solution using `cellfun` and `cell2mat`. Tested in MATLAB R2012a.

```
error(['atmlab:' mfilename ':invalid'], 'Invalid mode: %s. Valid modes: %s\n', mode, cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) [ x ' ' ], valid_modes, 'UniformOutput', false)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that will convert cell array into a string:

```
 function st = cell2str(cellStr)
     cellStr= cellfun(@(x){[x ',']},cellStr); %# Add ',' after each string.
     st = cat(2,cellStr{:});  %# Convert to string             
     st(end) = []; %# Remove last ','
 end
```

Note that in case that you only want to display the cell array, and not pass it as a string, you can use `celldisp` function.